# Modeling a data-store browser

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, hierarchical-data

I have a connection-object browser that I want to allow a user to view of various data sources they are connected to.The viewer of the objects look something like this:

- **Connection**: Remote.1234.MySQL (3 level source)

  - **Database**: Sales

    - **Table**: User

      - **Field**: Name -- CHAR(80)
      - **Field**: Age -- INT32
    - **Table**: Product

      - ...
    - **Table**: Purchase

      - ...
  - **Database**: Other

    - ...
- **Connection**: Remote.abc.ElasticSearch (2 level source)

  - **Index**: Inventory

    - **Field**: ID -- INTEGER
    - **Field**: Product -- STRING
    - ...
- **Connection**: Local.xyz.MongoDB (3 level source)

  - **Database**: Mail

    - **Collection**: Users

      - **Field**: MailboxID -- INTEGER
      - **Field**: Name -- STRING
    - **Collection**: Documents

      - ...
- **Connection**: Local.xyz.SQLServer (4 level source)

  - **Database**: Main

    - **Schema**: Public

      - **Table**: user

        - **Field**: Name -- STRING
  - **Database**: History

    - ...

In other words, a 'Source' is a hierarchy of a known number of levels and a known 'name' for each level. While the entire hierarchy is variable, the hierarchy of any given source will always have the same number of levels and name. What might be a good way to model this relationally? My thought was to have the following:

Connection:

- id
- host
- (other details)

SourceType:

- id
- Name

SourceTypeLevelMapping:

- SourceTypeID
- level (int)
- name

ThreeLevelSource_Level1: # e.g., Database

- ID
- ParentID (ConnectionID)
- Name
- (other details)

ThreeLevelSource_Level2: # e.g., Table

- ID
- ParentID (Level1ID)
- Name
- (other details)

ThreeLevelSource_Level3: # e.g., Field

- ID
- ParentID (Level2ID)
- FieldName
- FieldType
- (other details)

Then do the same for the other level-ed hierarchies:

- TwoLevelSource_Level1, TwoLevelSource_Level2
- FourLevelSource_Level1, FourLevelSource_Level2, FourLevelSource_Level3, FourLevelSource_Level4

---

So basically define the known hierarchies and for each new source that we add we would attach it to one of the known hierarchy levels. The alternative approach I was thinking of doing is to create a new hierarchy for each new source, but then we would be looking at literally hundreds of tables if we were to allow access to 25-50 sources.

What might be a good way to model this type of hierarchical data?

(Also, yes I am familiar with the existing general approaches for modeling hierarchical data as delineated here -- [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database), [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database) -- the below is not a duplicate.)

Comment: @David542 Rest assured, hierarchic data is handled very elegantly in Codd's [**Relational Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf), completely within the Rdb.  No need for OO (split Rdb constraints over to the middle tier & break the principle of an integral Rdb), no need for the inefficient methods given in links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Relational Solution

Responding to the `relational-database` and `hierarchic-data` tags, the latter being pedestrian in the former.

#### 1.1 Preliminary

Due to the requirement for, and the difference between:

- the genuine SQL Platforms (conformation to the Standard; server architecture, unified language; etc) and
- the pretend "SQL" programs (no architecture; bits of language spread across those programs; no Transactions; no ACID; etc) that provide no compliance to the Standard, and therefore use the term incorrectly, and
- the non-SQLs

Thus I use `Record` and `Field` to cover all possibilities, instead of the Relational terms, which would convey Relational definitions.

All possibilities are catered for, but a Relational and SQL-compliant approach (eg. MS SQL Server) is taken as the best method, due to its 40-year establishment and maturity, and the absence of alternatives.

- The collection of SQL Platforms; pretend "SQL" applications; and non-SQL suites, are labelled `DataSource`.

#### 1.2 Compliance

This solution is 100% Relational: Codd's [**Relational Model**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf), not the substandard alternatives marketed by the academics as "relational":

- It can be implemented in any SQL compliant Platform
- It has Relational Integrity (which is logical, beyond Referential Integrity, which is SQL and physical); Relational Power; and Relational Speed.
- All update interaction is simple, via SQL ACID Transactions.
- No warranties are given for pretend "SQLs" and non-SQLs.

---

### 2 Solution

#### 2.1 Concept

I appreciate that as a developer, your focus in on the data values and how to retrieve it.  However, two levels of definition are required first, in order to support the third data level:

1. **Catalogue Potential**
   Blue (Reference cluster).
   The DtaSources and definition that is available in the market, which the organisation might use.  Let's say 42, as per your descriptions.

   - I would entrust this only to a `developer`, not an `user_admin`, because the set up it critical (the lower levels depend on it), and it describes the *physical* capability and limitations of each DataSource.
2. **Catalogue Actual**
   Green (Identification cluster).
   The DataSources and definition that are actually contracted and used by the organisation.  Let's say 12.  At this point we have connection addresses; ports; and `users`.  It is constrained CataloguePotential, directly, and via `CHECKS` that call Functions.

   This level defines the content (the tables that actually exist), it contains no data values.

   - Maintaining an SQL mindset, because that would be the most prudent, given that it is an established Standard, with 40 years of maturity, because it gives us the most flexibility: the CatalogueActual forms the SQL Catalogue.
   - Likewise, I have used the terms `Record` and `Field` for the objects in the collective, rather than `Table` and `Column`, which would imply Relational and SQL meanings.
   - SQL Platform
     This level can be populated automatically by the program querying the SQL Catalogue.
   - "SQL" applications and non-SQL suites
     Population is manual due to the absence of a Catalogue.  It can be done by an `user_admin`.  The constraint would be your program attempting a trial query to validate the user-supplied table definition.
3. **Current Data**
   Yellow (Transaction cluster)
   The current data, that the `user` has queried from the DataSources, via his Connection, for the webpage.  The assumption is, I have taken the user::webpage to be central, and governing (one `user` per Connection; one `user` per webpage), not the OO Object.

   - if the OO Objects are not reliable (depends on the library you use), or there is one set of Objects across all user-webpages, more Constraints need to be added.

#### 2.2 Method

You need:

1. **Simple Hierarchy**
   a single-parent hierarchy to replicate the fixed levels of definition in the Catalogue in the SQL servers, as well as the variable levels in the constructed catalogue for the pretend "SQLs" and the non-SQLs.

   - Relational Hierarchies are fully defined, along with SQL implementation details, in the [**Hierarchy**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Hierarchy.pdf) doc.  The simple or single-parent model is given in [§ 2.2].
   - The **Root** level (not the Anchor) is the Potential DataSource
   - The **Leaf** level is that which contains data, either a `Record` or a `Struct` (for those in the collective that allow one).

     - In the Potential Datasource, it is representative, truly a `RecordType` and `FieldType`
     - In the Actual DataSource, it is an actual `Record`, which is an instance of `RecordType`, and actual `Field`, which is a narrower definition of `FieldType`.
2. **Method/Struct**
   In order to handle a `Struct`, which in definition terms is identical to a `Record`, and to allow a `Struct` to contain a `Struct`, we need a level of abstraction, which is ...

   - `Article`
     is either

     - a `Field`, which is the atomic unit of storage, xor
     - a `Struct`, which contains `Articles`
   - that requires an Exclusive Subtype cluster, fully defined along with SQL implementation details, in the [**Subtype**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) doc
3. **Method/Array**
   To support an `Array` of `Fields`:

   - These are multi-valued dependencies on `Field`, thus implemented as child tables.

     - For scalars the `NumElement` is 1.
     - That makes the Exclusive Subtype cluster on `Field` that is otherwise required for scalars redundant.

#### 2.3 Relational Data Model

This is the progress after seven iterations.  It shows the Table-Relation level (the Attribute level is too large for an inline graphic).

[image: foo]

1. **Assumption**
   That the JS (or whatever) objects are local to the webpage/user.  If your objects are global, the value tables need to be constrained to Connection.
2. The data model is given in a single [**PDF**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student_Resolutions_2020/David542/Browser/Browser%20TA%20V0_13.pdf):

   - Table Relation level
   - Table Relation level + sample data
   - Table Attribute level + sample data.

#### 2.4 Notation

- All my data models are rendered in [**IDEF1X**](https://www.iso.org/standard/60614.html), available from the early 1980's, the one and only notation for Relational Data Modelling, the Standard since 1993.
- The [**IDEF1X Introduction**](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for those who are new to Codd's *Relational Model*, or its modelling method.  Note that IDEF1X models complete, they are rich in detail and precision, showing *all* required details, whereas a home-grown model, being unaware of the imperatives of the Standard, have far less definition.  Which means, the notation needs to be fully understood.

Answer (score 4):

Here three working sqlite flavored implementations (once sqlite is being used, column types not being enforced are acceptable, only integer primary keys were used in order to act as rowid):

In all cases, sqlite foreign key PRAGMA is set to true: `PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;`

### Simple implementation - one fixed table for each source/level (constrained by foreign keys)

The following design/implementation utilizes one table for each type of database and level. Tables references one each other with foreign keys to ensure correctness. For example, a mongo `collection` can't be child of a mysql `database`. Only in the `connection` level all database types share the same table, but it could be different if it is expected different properties for each kind of `connection`.

```sql
create table databasetype(name primary key) without rowid;
insert into databasetype values ('mysql'),('elasticsearch'),('mongo'),('sqlserver');

create table datatype(name primary key) without rowid;
insert into datatype values ('int'),('str'); -- you can differentiate varchar if you will

create table connection(id integer, hostname, databasetype, primary key(id), foreign key(databasetype) references databasetype(name));

create table mysqldatabase(id integer, connectionid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(connectionid) references connection(id));
create table mysqltable(id integer, databaseid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(databaseid) references mysqldatabase(id));
create table mysqlfield(id integer, tableid, name, datatype, datalength, primary key(id), foreign key(tableid) references mysqltable(id), foreign key(datatype) references datatype(name));

create table elasticsearchindex(id integer, connectionid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(connectionid) references connection(id));
create table elasticsearchfield(id integer, indexid, name, datatype, datalength, primary key(id), foreign key(indexid) references mysqltable(id), foreign key(datatype) references datatype(name));

create table mongodatabase(id integer, connectionid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(connectionid) references connection(id));
create table mongocollection(id integer, databaseid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(databaseid) references mongodatabase(id));
create table mongofield(id integer, collectionid, name, datatype, datalength, primary key(id), foreign key(collectionid) references mongocollection(id), foreign key(datatype) references datatype(name));

create table sqlserverdatabase(id integer, connectionid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(connectionid) references connection(id));
create table sqlserverschema(id integer, databaseid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(databaseid) references sqlserverdatabase(id));
create table sqlservertable(id integer, schemaid, name, primary key(id), foreign key(schemaid) references sqlserverschema(id));
create table sqlserverfield(id integer, tableid, name, datatype, datalength, primary key(id), foreign key(tableid) references sqlservertable(id), foreign key(datatype) references datatype(name));
```

Loading data representing the first table:

```sql
insert into connection(hostname, databasetype) values ('remote:1234', 'mysql');
insert into mysqldatabase(connectionid, name) select id, 'sales' from connection where hostname='remote:1234';
insert into mysqltable(databaseid, name) select id, 'user' from mysqltable where name='sales';
insert into mysqlfield(tableid, name, datatype, datalength) select id, 'name', 'str', 80 from mysqldatabase where name='product';
insert into mysqlfield(tableid, name, datatype) select id, 'age', 'i32' from mysqldatabase where name='product';
```

Trying invalid manipulations of data:

```sql
insert into mysqlfield(tableid, name, datatype) values (2, 'newfield', 'qubit');

-- Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

In order to pretty-print the whole tree it is necessary to do a manual join of all tables involved.

#### Graph like implementation - one table representing the tree, other the hierarchy (constrained by triggers)

Here the `element` table is used to represent each element/node in the tree. Its `level` column explicitly classifies each element as an `database`, `table`, etc. Here sqlite's rowid is being used as the primary key, but it is easy to change it to a regular id.

In the previous implementation, foreign keys were used to ensure model correctness. Now triggers are used for this job. They decide which parent level accepts which child level, as it is allowed for the respective dbtype - those rules are specified on the `element_type` table.

Lastly, an exra table `element_properties`, is used to allow extra properties to be attached to any elements, such as field type.

```sql
create table db_type(name primary key) without rowid;
insert into db_type values ('mysql'),('elasticsearch'),('mongo'),('sqlserver');

create table element_type(parentlevel, childlevel, dbtype, primary key(parentlevel, childlevel, dbtype), foreign key(dbtype) references db_type(name)); --not using without rowid to be able to have null parent level
insert into element_type values
  (null, 'connection', 'mysql'),
  ('connection', 'database', 'mysql'),
  ('database', 'table', 'mysql'),
  ('table', 'field', 'mysql'),

  (null, 'connection', 'elasticsearch'),
  ('connection', 'index', 'elasticsearch'),
  ('index','field', 'elasticsearch'),

  (null, 'connection', 'mongo'),
  ('connection', 'database', 'mongo'),
  ('database', 'collection', 'mongo'),
  ('collection', 'field', 'mongo'),

  (null, 'connection', 'sqlserver'),
  ('connection', 'database', 'sqlserver'),
  ('database', 'schema', 'sqlserver'),
  ('schema', 'table', 'sqlserver'),
  ('table', 'field', 'sqlserver');

create table element(id integer, parentid, name, level, dbtype, primary key(id), foreign key(parentid) references element(id), foreign key(dbtype) references db_type(name));

create table element_property(parentid, name, value, primary key(parentid, name), foreign key(parentid) references element(id)) without rowid;

-- trigger to guarantee that new elements will conform hierarchy
create trigger element_insert before insert on element
begin
  select iif(count(*)>0, 'ok', raise(abort,'invalid parent-child insertion')) from element_type etc join element_type etp on (etp.childlevel, etp.dbtype)=(etc.parentlevel, etc.dbtype) where (etc.dbtype, etc.parentlevel, etc.childlevel)=(new.dbtype, (select level from element ei where ei.rowid=new.parentid), new.level);
end;

-- trigger to guarantee that updated elements will conform hierarchy
create trigger element_update before update on element
begin
  select iif(count(*)>0, 'ok', raise(abort,'invalid parent-child update')) from element_type etc join element_type etp on (etp.childlevel, etp.dbtype)=(etc.parentlevel, etc.dbtype) where (etc.dbtype, etc.parentlevel, etc.childlevel)=(new.dbtype, (select level from element ei where ei.rowid=new.parentid), new.level);
end;

-- trigger to guarantee that hierarchy removal must respect existing elements (no delete cascade used)
create trigger element_type_delete before delete on element_type
begin
  select iif(count(*)>0, raise(abort,'can''t remove, entries found in the element table using this relationship'), 'ok') from element etc join element etp on etp.rowid=etc.parentid and etp.dbtype=etp.dbtype where etc.dbtype=old.dbtype and (etp.level,etc.level)=(old.parentlevel, old.childlevel);
end;

-- trigger to guarantee that hierarchy changes must respect existing elements
create trigger element_type_update before update on element_type
begin
  select iif(count(*)>0, raise(abort,'can''t change, entries found in the element table using this relationship'), 'ok') from element etc join element etp on etp.rowid=etc.parentid and etp.dbtype=etp.dbtype where etc.dbtype=old.dbtype and (etp.level,etc.level)=(old.parentlevel, old.childlevel) and (etp.level,etc.level)!=(new.parentlevel, new.childlevel);
end;
```

Loading data representing the first table:

```sql
insert into element(name, level, dbtype) values ('remote:1234', 'connection', 'mysql');
insert into element(name, level, dbtype, parentid) values ('sales', 'database', 'mysql', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('connection', 'remote:1234', 'mysql')));
insert into element(name, level, dbtype, parentid) values ('user', 'table', 'mysql', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('database', 'sales', 'mysql')));
insert into element(name, level, dbtype, parentid) values ('name', 'field', 'mysql', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('table', 'user', 'mysql')));
insert into element(name, level, dbtype, parentid) values ('age', 'field', 'mysql', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('table', 'user', 'mysql')));
insert into element_property(name, value, parentid) values ('fieldtype', 'varchar', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('field', 'name', 'mysql')));
insert into element_property(name, value, parentid) values ('fieldlength', 80, (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('field', 'name', 'mysql')));
insert into element_property(name, value, parentid) values ('fieldtype', 'integer', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('field', 'age', 'mysql')));
```

Trying invalid manipulations of data:

```sql
insert into element(name, level, dbtype, parentid) values ('documents', 'collection', 'mysql', (select id from element where (level, name, dbtype)=('database', 'sales', 'mysql')));

-- Error: invalid parent-child insertion

update element_type set childlevel='specialfield' where dbtype='mysql' and (parentlevel, childlevel)=('table','field');

-- Error: can't change, entries found in the element table using this relationship
```

Pretty-printing the tree:

```sql
create view elementree(path) as
with recursive cte(id, name, depth, dbtype, level) as (
  select id, name, 0 as depth, dbtype, level from element where parentid is null
  union all
  select el.id, el.name, cte.depth+1 as depth, el.dbtype, el.level from element el join cte on el.parentid=cte.id
  order by depth desc
)
select substring('     ',0,2*depth)||name||' ('||dbtype||'-'||level||')' from cte;

select * from elementree;
-- remote:1234 (mysql-connection)
--  sales (mysql-database)
--    user (mysql-table)
--    documents (mysql-table)
--      name (mysql-field)
--      age (mysql-field)
```

### Minimalist DRY graph like implementation - one table with only names representing the tree and only one auxiliar table

Here again it is used an `element` table to represent each element in the tree. Differently from the previous case, the table has less information and the type of each element - whether it is a `database` or a `table` is implicitly inferred instead of explicitly determined by a column. By simply adding an `user` as a child of `sales`, it is inferred that `user` is a mysql `table`, once it is child of a mysql `database` - `sales`, which is a`database` because it is child of a mysql `connection`, which is child of the `mysql` root element. Dbtypes are root elements in this tree, all their children are inferred to be of this dbtype.

Here the `hierarchypath` table was used to tell the hierarchy that has be followed in the `element` tree. For the user confort, (s)he will only have to insert a (`>` separated) string representing the hierarchy path, starting from dbtype. The hierarchy view will desconstruct this string to the hierachy structure. One example of a hirearcy path would be: `mysql>connection>database>table>field`.

Note that again, sqlite's rowid is used as table id. Remember that it is not possible to see rowid by simply `select * from table;`, it is hidden by default, it is needed to explicitly select it: `select rowid,* from table;`.

```sql
create table element(name, parentrowid, foreign key(parentrowid) references element(rowid));
-- dbtypes are the root elements
insert into element(name) values ('mysql'),('elasticsearch'),('mongo'),('sqlserver');

create table hierarchypath(path);

insert into hierarchypath values
  ('mysql>connection>database>table>field'),
  ('elasticsearch>connection>index>field'),
  ('mongo>connection>database>collection>field'),
  ('sqlserver>connection>schema>database>table>field');
```

Loading data:

```sql
insert into element select 'remote:1234',rowid from element where (name,coalesce(parentrowid,-1))=('mysql',-1); --returning rowid; -- returning only works for sqlite 3.35+
insert into element select 'sales',rowid from element where rowid=5;
insert into element select 'user',rowid from element where rowid=6;
insert into element select 'name',rowid from element where rowid=7;
insert into element select 'age',rowid from element where rowid=7;
```

Pretty-printing:

```sql
create view hierarchy(root, depth, name) as
with recursive hierarchycte(root, depth, name, remaining) as (
  select substr(path, 0, instr(path, '>')) as root, 0 as depth, substr(path, 0, instr(path, '>')) as name, substr(path, instr(path, '>')+1)||'>' as remaining from hierarchypath
  union all
  select root, depth+1 as depth, substr(remaining, 0, instr(remaining, '>')) as name, substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '>')+1) as remaining from hierarchycte where instr(remaining, '>') > 0
)
select root, depth, name from hierarchycte where depth>=0;

create view elementhierarchy(root, depth, name) as
with recursive elementcte(root, depth, name, rowid, parentrowid) as (
  select name as root, 0 as depth, name, rowid, parentrowid from element where parentrowid is null
  union all
  select elcte.root, elcte.depth+1, el.name, el.rowid, el.parentrowid from elementcte elcte join element el on el.parentrowid=elcte.rowid
  order by depth desc
)
select root, depth, name from elementcte;

create view elementree as
with recursive elementcte(root, depth, name, rowid, parentrowid) as (
  select name as root, 0 as depth, name, rowid, parentrowid from element where parentrowid is null
  union all
  select elcte.root, elcte.depth+1, el.name, el.rowid, el.parentrowid from elementcte elcte join element el on el.parentrowid=elcte.rowid
  order by depth desc
)
select substring('     ',0,2*h.depth-2)||eh.name||' ('||h.root||'-'||h.name||')' from (select *,row_number() over () as originalorder from elementhierarchy) eh join hierarchy h on (eh.root,eh.depth)=(h.root,h.depth) where h.depth>0 order by originalorder;

select * from elementree;
-- remote:1234 (mysql-connection)
--  sales (mysql-database)
--    user (mysql-table)
--      age (mysql-field)
--      name (mysql-field)
```

Triggers were not implemented here, but it would be good to do so. One example would be to avoid inserting more levels than allowed.

It would be wiser to store the hierarchy in the desconstructed form seen on the view
hierarchy, by doing the desconstruction in insertion time instead of every select query to avoid cpu consumption. Here it was left this way to differentiate it more from other implementations.

Here the last level entity, the `field` have no properties as shown on previous implementations. In this model it would be necessary to add one or two extra levels to the hierarchy: `...table>field>fieldpropertyandvalue` or `...table>field>fieldproperty>fieldpropertyvalue`, in the first case an example of `fieldpropertyandvalue` would be `datatype=integer` and an example of separated property and values would be respectively `datatype` and `integer`. This approach where any properties are new nodes in the graph is closer to the approach used by RDF stores.

---

To conclude it must be stated that it would be possible to use specialized graph databases, using their own query languages like cypher in neo4j and sparql in others or even other languages, but since the graph design overall is simple, a relational database suffice our needs.